# How to add multiple results to an JSF form

Tags: ajax, jsf

Hi there i currently have a web page that uses ajax on submit to display the message the user entered on the same page below the input box, what i am wondering, if it is possible to keep a record of all messages inputted such as message 1, message 2 etc all displayed under them?

what is the best method for this ? also is there a way to do this with out the user having to press the submit button each time ?

this is my code so far :

```
<h:body>
    <h3>JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example</h3>

    <h:form>
       <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
       <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
         <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
       </h:commandButton>

       <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>    
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

my bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSayWelcome(){
       //check if null?
       if("".equals(name) || name ==null){
        return "";
       }else{
        return "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to change your bean. Make the attribute a `List<String>` to store all of the messages.

After that, to show the list you need to change `output` to a component that allows for showing all elements of the `List`; v.g. `dataTable`.

Also, you will need to invoke an action method in you ajax request, because your application will need to execute some logic (add `name` to the list).